# white page in taxonomy terms url

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, uri, wsod

I am using drupal 7, when I am going to path of  terms I see only white page, no error and nothing in another page I have not this problem, 
 some php properties are :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_WARNING
max_execution_time = 360 
max_input_time = 120 
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
mbstring.func_overload = 2
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
```

where is the problem? and how can I solve it?

Comment: `memory_limit` seems to me too low. Set it to minimum of 64M and check if it works then.

Comment: Is there any custom module in your website?

Comment: @JayendraKainthola No,

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. I test with memory_limit=256M but nothing happened :(

Comment: Did you restarted apache?

Comment: There is a long list of possible causes and solutions for 'White Screen of Death': https://drupal.org/node/158043 You can scan them to find out what it could be in your case.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. the blank white page is in all of pages, but my problem is only in term path :( . also my memry_limit taked efftect I test it by checking phpinfo

Comment: @zhilevan,  Have you checked if there is any `die` or `exit` in any module file?

Comment: @JayendraKainthola , I am working with ftp of site and searching in all of content for die need time,I suggest this but dont find any die. I go to call back of term function  in `/**
 * Menu callback; displays all nodes associated with a term.
 *
 * @param $term
 *   The taxonomy term.
 * @return
 *   The page content.
 */
function taxonomy_term_page($term) {
    die('in taxonomy call back term page ,inserted here by YM for debugging');`  but after put this dont see my die , I think the problem is before  hook_menu  $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']  . really I am confused

Comment: @zhilevan, its very confused issue as there is not a simple solution for this.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola , yes I know, I should try every solution come to my mind :(. tnx for your attention (y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to do when you get the WSOD is to turn on all error reporting to see what led up to the failure to produce output.  The `error_reporting` setting you show is turning of a lot of reporting.

You'll get more runtime error reporting by adding this to the start of `settings.php` on your site (you add it just below `<?php`):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

In addition, navigate to: Administration→ Configuration→ Development → logging and errors and select All messages. This sets `$conf['error_level'] = 2;`.

Also, check the logs (in particular most recent log messages).

If I should try to guess, I would say you're out of memory.  Having a 32M `memory_limit` when running Drupal 7 does sound like a source for trouble (I've no Drupal 7 site with less than 128M).

Comment: I test this , right now , but not see any error in white page,  this problem only in taxonomy term url :(

Comment: I  set memory_limit=256M and test ,but nothing happened :(.